# How do I use HTML to code this header type element?

Tags: html, css

I've coded the html for the image located at http://tinypic.com/r/fxcu9j/5 which can be seen below:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pricing Table</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="column">
            <ul>
                <h2>Basic $9<small>pm</small></h2>
                <li>256gb Bandwidth</li>
                <li>Unlimited Addon Domains</li>
                <li>50gb Disk Space</li>
                <li>cPanel Access &amp; Fantastico</li>
                <li>24/7 Live Support</li>
                <li>Email Accounts</li>
                <li>Free Domain</li>
                <li><a href="#" class="button">Sign Up Now</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've omitted replicating the container class for the sake of simplicity and my question is this: Should the headings for each column (which contain the package name and price) be part of the list items even though I want to target them later for CSS where I'll change the colour and add a pipe symbol or should I separate this section within the HTML? If so, in what way should I separate the top section from the unordered list?

As you can see I've used an h2 tag in the meantime but I know this is incorrect. I've studied code from other sites but have not yet found an example such as this.

If possible, could you refer me to an online example of this structure or some other site where I can reference related reading material?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: FYI: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142857

Comment: You should paste your code here in a code block rather than link to an image of text.

Comment: You might want to do some reading on how CSS (Cascading styles Sheets) work. This is an extremely basic question

Comment: @JohnFx I've been learning about HTML/HTML5 and CSS for about 2 weeks now and am very much a beginner so you'll have to excuse my asking such a basic question. I ask not out of laziness and have even shown my full code in an attempt to show my grasp of the concepts. If you could refer me to material in particular relation to this solution I would really appreciate that, however this screenshot is all I have to work with and therefore cannot tinker with the source code. I don't need anyone to do my coding for me, I just need someone to point me in a non-vague direction. Could you perhaps help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be missing something here, but you can style your `h2` tags in CSS by simply doing something like this:

```
h2 {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Or, since you have a different color for each header, you can assign them an `id` and style them accordingly.

HTML:

```
<h2 id="blue">Basic $9<small>pm</small></h2>
...
<h2 id="red">Free $0<small>pm</small></h2>
```

CSS:

```
#blue {
    background-color: blue;
}
#red {
    background-color: red;
}
```

See this example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/DrydenLong/GGUCM/)

***Update***

This [link](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2008/08/13/top-10-css-table-designs/) applies to tables, but will give you a good idea where to start with your CSS. I'm sure most of it can be adjusted to suit your list layout. #10 on the page looks close to what you are after.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I kept thinking I needed to break up my HTML in order to accommodate the styling of the first list item which was an h2 tag in this case. I was stumped and the solution is so simple. And thank you for pointing to jsFiddle too. What a great resource that will be to test with in the future. Thank you once again. You've made my day :)

Comment: @Pein No problem, good luck with your work!

Comment: Fantastic stuff! Thank you again for going the extra mile and sharing the link with the tables. You Rock! I'm really glad you found my question. Wish I could return the favour. If you think of anything let me know!